# How to store arrays of data in object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

how  to store arrays of data in an Object. I tried to store data using

```
 var namelist = [], labelDetails   = {};
 addedLabels_list.push(name);
 labedDetails_list[ownerName] = Address;
```

namelist holds unique names while **labelDetails store data in key value pair**

```
Namelist :
0:"ahmad"
1:"jhon"
2: "hamza"
3: "emma"

labelDetails :
ahmad :"lahore"
jhon :"USA"
hamza :"UK"
emma :"USA, Calforina"
```

But when same **owner name has multiple addresses** it won't work. 
Let's say `Emma` live in `USA, California` and her second address is `Washington Dc`

and it replaces `emma :"washington dc"`

```
 var namelist = [], labelDetails   = {};
 addedLabels_list.push(name);
 labedDetails_list[ownerName] = Address;
```

Comment: Hey, you can use some array to store multiple address for a same object, something like emma : ["USA, Calforina", "washington, dc"].

Comment: Why don't you just append the `address`? like this : `labedDetails_list[ownerName] += " - "+ Address;`

Comment: Thats kind of obvious isn't it? The key should be a unique one.

Comment: i want to check same name and address wont repeat @HamzaAbdaoui

Comment: Yes @AbhilashNayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try designing a data structure that also stays stable over time, thus choosing a name based (better id based) key-value person-registry that for each person refers a single data item. This data node then is the root for all person related data that yet will come and then has to be taken care of as well ...

```js
var personRegistry = {
  ahmad: {
    addressList: ["Lahore"]
  },
  jhon: {
    addressList: ["USA"]
  },
  hamza: {
    addressList: ["UK"]
  },
  emma: {
    addressList: ["USA, California"]
  }
}


function storeAddress(name, address) {
  var store = personRegistry[name];
  if (!store) {
    store = personRegistry[name] = {};
    store.addressList = [];
  }
  // prevent address duplicates ...
//if (!store.addressList.includes(address)) { // use that if available.
  if (store.addressList.indexOf(address) < 0) {
    store.addressList.push(address);
  }
}


console.log('personRegistry : ', personRegistry);

storeAddress("emma", 'USA, California');
storeAddress("emma", 'USA, Washington DC');
storeAddress("emma", 'USA, Washington DC');

storeAddress("susan", 'Canada, Toronto');
storeAddress("susan", 'Canada, Toronto');

console.log('personRegistry : ', personRegistry);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For arrays, the key should be unique, so in this case, you can use array to store multiple address for a the same key, this is a start :

```js
function myFunction(){
 var namelist = ["ahmad", "jhon", "hamza", "emma"], 
   labelDetails   = {ahmad :["lahore"], jhon :["USA"], hamza :["UK"], emma :["USA, Calforina"]};
  labelDetails["emma"].push("washington dc");
  console.log(labelDetails);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="javascript:myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely have to make some changes to make your solution work, I would suggest,

```
labelDetails   = {
    "ahmad" : ["lahore"],
    "jhon" : ["USA"],
    "hamza" : ["UK"],
    "emma" : ["USA, Calforina"]
 };

labelDetails[ownerName].push("washington dc");
```